# How to calculate reverse distance weight for 1D situation?

Tags: r

This is an example dataframe:

```
test = data.frame('id'=c('1','2','3'),'value'=c(4,6,8),'score'=c(5,7,9))

test
  id value score
1  1     4     5
2  2     6     7
3  3     8     9
```

I'm looking for a Mark for each record:

[image: formula]

I did run through some packages (e.g.[here](http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/pubs/spherekit/inverse.html) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ipdw/vignettes/ipdw2.html)) for inverse distance weighing for 2D interpolation, but I feel that I'm not in the right direction for my problem. Could anyone please give me any hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can start with `weight <- outer(dat$value, dat$value, function(a,b) 1/abs(a-b))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hint given

```
test = data.frame('id'=c('1','2','3'),'value'=c(4,6,8),'score'=c(5,7,9))
weight <- outer(test$value, test$value, function(a,b) 1/abs(a-b))
for(i in 1:length(test$score)){
 test$mark[i] <- sum(test$score[-i]*weight[-i,i])/sum(weight[-i,i])
}
```

Comment: Thought there is a package, but this solves the problem, thanks!